# Vaadin and Spring - @Autowired field is null

Tags: java, spring, vaadin, autowired, vaadin4spring

my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24472459/vaadin-spring-integration-autowired-nullpointerexception) was marked as duplicated, but answers not work for me :-(

I have two classes in the same package and I need to find object from @Service and print result to log.

```
package com.example.test.springvaadin.vaadin;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import com.example.test.springvaadin.entity.Role;
import com.example.test.springvaadin.service.RoleManager;

@Controller
public class Test { 
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Test.class);

    @Autowired
    private RoleManager roleManager;

    @RequestMapping("/test")
    public void doTest() {
        Role role = roleManager.findById(1);
        logger.info("_ROLE_TEST_ " + role.toString());
        String text = role.getName();       
    }
}
```

If I go to *http://ip.ip.ip.ip:8080/springvaadin/test* I see in log (good):

```
14:27:09.126 [tomcat-http--4] INFO  c.e.test.springvaadin.vaadin.Test - _ROLE_TEST_ Role [id=1, name=Test]
```

There is second class:

```
package com.example.test.springvaadin.vaadin;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.vaadin.spring.VaadinUI;

import com.example.test.springvaadin.entity.Role;
import com.example.test.springvaadin.service.RoleManager;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinRequest;
import com.vaadin.ui.Label;
import com.vaadin.ui.UI;
import com.vaadin.ui.VerticalLayout;

@Controller // @Component do not work too
@VaadinUI
public class MainUI extends UI {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MainUI.class);

    @Autowired
    private RoleManager roleManager;

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        logger.info("MAINUI IN INIT");
        final VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
        layout.setMargin(true);
        setContent(layout);

        Role role = roleManager.findById(1);
        logger.info("_ROLE_VAADIN_ " + role.toString());
        String text = role.getName();

        Label lblRoleName = new Label(text);
        layout.addComponent(lblRoleName);       
    }
}
```

it is mapped by web.xml to */ui*. At page *http://ip.ip.ip.ip:8080/springvaadin/ui* I get HTTP 500:

```
14:29:50.810 [tomcat-http--14] INFO  c.e.test.springvaadin.vaadin.MainUI - MAINUI IN INIT
Čer 29, 2014 2:29:50 ODP. com.vaadin.server.DefaultErrorHandler doDefault
SEVERE: 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.test.springvaadin.vaadin.MainUI.init(MainUI.java:40)
    at com.vaadin.ui.UI.doInit(UI.java:641)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UIInitHandler.getBrowserDetailsUI(UIInitHandler.java:222)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UIInitHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UIInitHandler.java:74)
    at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:41)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1405)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:237)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:409)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1044)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Čer 29, 2014 2:29:50 ODP. org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [MainUI] in context with path [/springvaadin] threw exception [com.vaadin.server.ServiceException: java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.test.springvaadin.vaadin.MainUI.init(MainUI.java:40)
    at com.vaadin.ui.UI.doInit(UI.java:641)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UIInitHandler.getBrowserDetailsUI(UIInitHandler.java:222)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UIInitHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UIInitHandler.java:74)
    at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:41)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1405)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:237)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:409)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1044)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.test.springvaadin.vaadin.MainUI.init(MainUI.java:40)

but it is last line in class after last *}* in file.

Spring knows where are clasees located:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.test.springvaadin.controller" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.test.springvaadin.dao" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.test.springvaadin.service" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.test.springvaadin.vaadin" />
```

What I do bad? Used annotation?

Source code: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6943408/vaadin-spring_.zip

---

Update 1:

I remove @Controller annotation from *MainUI* class and now it crash on line 31 - "Role role = roleManager.findById(1);" There is error:

```
Čer 29, 2014 8:50:22 ODP. com.vaadin.server.DefaultErrorHandler doDefault
SEVERE: 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.test.springvaadin.vaadin.MainUI.init(MainUI.java:31)
    at com.vaadin.ui.UI.doInit(UI.java:641)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UIInitHandler.getBrowserDetailsUI(UIInitHandler.java:222)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UIInitHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UIInitHandler.java:74)
    at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:41)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1405)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:237)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:409)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1044)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Čer 29, 2014 8:50:22 ODP. org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [MainUI] in context with path [/springvaadin] threw exception [com.vaadin.server.ServiceException: java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.test.springvaadin.vaadin.MainUI.init(MainUI.java:31)
    at com.vaadin.ui.UI.doInit(UI.java:641)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UIInitHandler.getBrowserDetailsUI(UIInitHandler.java:222)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UIInitHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UIInitHandler.java:74)
    at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:41)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1405)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:237)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:409)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1044)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: The @Controller annotation looks redundant on MainUI. Remove it and see what happens.

Comment: I remove @Controller and now it crash on line 31 - "Role role = roleManager.findById(1);" There is error: http://pastebin.com/YPCfA2D0

Comment: Try using SpringAwareVaadinServlet

Comment: I try SpringAwareVaadinServlet but it does not work. I do an error :-(

Comment: i have The same problem
can u help me?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25121281/use-spring-in-vaadin

Answer (score 0):

If you [search the repository](https://vaadin.com/directory#browse%3avaadin,search=spring) you can see that you have 2 or 3 options. I personally use the [spring-vaadin-integration plugin](https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/springvaadinintegration%3avaadin) and according to [its documentation](http://vaadin.xpoft.ru/), instead of supplying the UI class as you'd do with a regular vaadin servlet:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MainUI</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet</servlet-class>      
    <init-param>
        <param-name>UI</param-name>
        <param-value>com.example.test.springvaadin.vaadin.MainUI</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

you need to supply the spring bean name

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MainUI</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>ru.xpoft.vaadin.SpringVaadinServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>beanName</param-name>
        <param-value>mainUI</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

Of course your UI should be annotated with `@Component` and probably `@Scope("prototype")`:

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class MainUI extends UI {    

    @Autowired
    private RoleManager roleManager;

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        final VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
        layout.setMargin(true);
        setContent(layout);

        Role r = new Role();
        r.setId(1);
        r.setName("Test");
        roleManager.save(r);

        String text = roleManager.findById(1).getName();

        Label lblRoleName = new Label(text);
        layout.addComponent(lblRoleName);       
    }
}
```

Comment: Now it crash on "ru.xpoft.vaadin.SpringUIProvider - found BEAN_NAME_PARAMETER: mainUI" - http://pastebin.com/yuDZqnsz

Comment: 1) Did you annotate the UI with `@Component`? 2) What's the UI class name?

Comment: Please put the `org.springframework` package on DEBUG log level and attach the full log, since the server was starting up

Comment: From the logs: `02:29:56.349 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loaded 0 bean definitions from location pattern [/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]` The `root-context.xml` which you are specifying as `contextConfigLocation` in `web.xml` has no bean definitions

Comment: Can you please help me fix it? Normal JSP and controllers works good.

Comment: I add *<bean id="mainUI" class="com.example.test.springvaadin.vaadin.MainUI" />* to *root-context.xml* and I still get *NullPointerException*. Vaddin class without any spring autowired works good.

Comment: You seem to want to use the beans and repositories that you've defined  in the `spring-servlet.xml`, so why not use that one instead?

Comment: I add `<bean id="mainUI" class="com.example.test.springvaadin.vaadin.MainUI" />` to `spring-servlet.xml` and I still get NullPointerException. Vaddin class without any spring autowired works good.

Comment: As I said, adding just the UI won't suffice because you want to access the beans defined in `spring-servlet.xml` which is not imported in the `root-context.xml`. Either import it or modify your `web.xml` to use the `spring-servlet.xml`. If you're still getting a NPE, post the stack-trace and relevant code.

Comment: i have The same problem
can u help me?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25121281/use-spring-in-vaadin